# IE8 support ES3. not ES5 or more. could babel help it?

Tags: javascript

i use ES6 and babel to compatible with ES5.

but i have to support IE8's ES3

the error said ' expected identifier '.

so i apply es3ify, member-expression-literals, property-literals, module-literals

and etc. but they did not work

that's why i am here

i think the ' .dafualt' is reserved word.

yesterday, i found this link

https://phabricator.babeljs.io/T7199

in the end, a person said that it worked.

but not for me. these are my codes.

```
var babelQuery = {
  presets: ['es2015-loose'],
  plugins: [
    "transform-runtime",
    "transform-proto-to-assign",
    "transform-es3-modules-literals",
    "transform-es3-member-expression-literals",
    "transform-es3-property-literals"
  ]
}
```

and

webpack.config

```
module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        include: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader', `babel?${JSON.stringify(babelQuery)}`,  ] //'babel',
      },
    ],
  }
```

what did i bad thing?

also, i did it without `exclude: /node_modules/` but same results.

Comment: You should have written the code to be compatible with ECMAScript ed 3 to start with, difficult to do that now since you may be using features that can't be made compatible. There are polyfills to get most of the way from ed 3 to 5.1, e.g. [*es5-shim*](https://github.com/es-shims/es5-shim).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, know that unless you write the code for ES3, no solutions are guaranteed to work.

I'd say you should try the [Babel polyfill](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/polyfill/). [Their website](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/caveats/) says

> Since Babel assumes that your code will run in an ES5 environment it uses ES5 functions. So if you’re using an environment that has limited or no support for ES5 such as lower versions of IE then using babel-polyfill will add support for these methods.